# Rails will not install on CentOS 6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

CentOS 6.5
Ruby 1.9.3
RubyGems 1.8.24

Can not install Rails (logged in as 'root').  I get the following error:

ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR: While executing gem ...(NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand

yum install zlib shows packaged installed already and latest version

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://imbaprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/11/installing-ruby-on-rail-on-centos-6-64.html

The above is the best set of instructions I have found for installing Ruby, Gems, Rails and Sqlite.  Just one typo error but all else worked well for me on CentOS 6.5.

The typo is where the instructions say to 'Install the sqlite-ruby'.  The command should read:

gem install **sqlite3-ruby**

Also, I found that nodejs is needed in order to start the rails server.  If missing you will get a JavaScript runtime error when trying to start the rails server.

yum install nodejs

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You should install necessary libraries **before** installing `ruby`.

try `yum install gcc-c++ glibc-headers openssl-devel readline libyaml-devel readline-devel zlib zlib-devel`

Then try rebuild `ruby`.

I recommend you to use `rbenv` and `ruby-build` plugin for `rbenv`.
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv
https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build

Comment: I use RVM.  I have installed the necessary libraries.  How can I ensure that the Ruby build is good?